# Adding item to data structure (C)

Tags: c, pointers, hashset

I am working with the library C-Collections and I have some troubles with the HashSet. Say I want to add numbers from a loop to the set like this:

```
for (int j = 0; j < M; ++j) {
        if (Matrix[j][i] == 1) {
            int* key_I_want_to_add = &j;
            if(hashset_add(the_set, key_I_want_to_ad) != CC_OK)
                printf("error");
            else {
                printf("added tool %d to job %d -- ", tool, i);
                printf("size is now %d ", hashset_size(tools));
            }
        }
    }
```

This adds the address of the key to the set. The problem is that at each loop, the key is reassigned the same address and it overwrites the first one. The size of the set stays to 1. The prototype of the add function is

```
enum cc_stat hashset_add(HashSet *set, void *element);
```

How am I supposed to proceed. I am currently learning C it's probably something trivial...

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like this hashset implementation expects a pointer to the item to add.  The reason you only ever have 1 element in the list is because you keep passing it the same address, i.e. the address of `j`.  Additionally, once you leave the outer `for` loop `j` goes out of scope so the pointer you saved is no longer valid.

You'll need to dynamically allocate memory for each element you want to add:

```
        int *key_I_want_to_add = malloc(sizeof(int));
        *key_I_want_to_add = j;
        if(hashset_add(the_set, key_I_want_to_ad) != CC_OK)
            printf("error");
```

Don't forget to clean up this memory when you're done using the hashset.

Comment: Ok thank you. Annoying thing with the memory clean is that I need to code a new destroy function for the hashset. I guess it's fine the HashSet is supposed to be in the memory for almost the entire algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

You are just adding the pointer to the local variable `j` every time. Your library is probably just storing the pointers (so in this case, it is storing the same pointer every time to `j`.You can either dynamically allocate a new `int` (which is probably more correct but seems wasteful in terms of memory and cycles) or just cast the value as a `void *` pointer:

```
hashset_add(the_set, (void *)j);
```

Now, is that what you really want though? I am not sure if you really meant to store the integers 0...M-1, because that's what this code would do.

Comment: Yes yes, I simplified the code for the question. Normally it selects relevant integers. What does it do exactly when I cast into (void*) ? Will the entries in the set be still accessible in the rest of my program ?

Comment: It'll just store the value of `j` (0, 1, 2, ... M-1). The cast just tells the compiler to treat `j` as a `void *` type instead of an `int`.